# How to use WiFi and 3G networks at the same time programmatically

Tags: android, networking, wifi, 3g, 3g-network

I am developing an application which need to use both networks at the same time - via WiFi the app has connection with some external device, and control it, using of 3G network needs to download a firmware for device. But the problem is when you connect to WiFi the system automatically do the disconnect of 3G network. It seems that WiFi has high priority than 3G network, but I need to use them at the same time, it's wrong behavior of the system for me in this case

I saw a couple similar questions, but they have no solution. Is really android has no way for developers to control both networks even for versions higher than 4.03?

How we can solve the problem?

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK to support this until the "L" Developer Preview (and I'm not 100% certain what's in "L" will help you here either). Note that the behavior that you are describing should only be if you are using WiFi connected to an access point -- I would not expect WiFiDirect, for example, to exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Off-topic. Please ask on www.android.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your advice. The external device which should be controlled by my application has own Wifi network, but not support WiFiDirect as I know

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a linear fashion. Turn off the wifi and download the firmware. Subsequently re-connect to the device (re-enable the wifi) and transfer the locally stored firmware.

Comment: Yep :) Now the app has the same workflow like described above. But user need manually switch the networks (turn OFF Wifi for enabling 3G mobile network, moreover user need to be ensure that settings flag of "use 3G" is activated). The users like UI is user friendly, all should looks easy with a minimum taps/clicks/switches.

Comment: The current worklow now: 1) turn ON wifi to connect a device "A" (we need to read a model of device and firmaware's current version); 2) Turn OFF Wifi - switch to 3G - request to server about new firmware version (if newest - download it); 3) Turn ON Wifi - connect again to device and transfer a just downloaded file;

Comment: This scenario is very difficult for a lot of users. If both networks will be available at the same time user no need to switch between networks.